# How to avoid reading body twice in Spring Webflux?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have an object `MultiMeasurement` in body that has one Status and `1` to `n` measurements.

I have to save status and measurements in repositories, emit events with them and return proper response from the endpoint.

```
fun save(multiMeasurement: Mono<MultiMeasurement>) =
    multiMeasurement.map(MultiMeasurement::validate)
        .flatMapMany { measurementCollector.save(it) }
        .doOnNext { eventSender.sendEvent(it.toMeasurementItem()) }
        .then(statusFacade.save(multiMeasurement))
        .doOnNext { eventSender.sendEvent(it.toStatusUpdateItem()) }
        .flatMap { toSettings(it.deviceId) }
```

Problem with the following code is that body is read twice - first in `map` operator and secondly inside `then`.

Both - `statusFacade` and `measurementCollector` save objects in reactive way (mongo) and return appropriate `Mono`s.

Result of `onOperatorDebug`:

```
|_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ com.openbrewery.beerbob.status.StatusCollector.save(StatusCollector.kt:15)
|_  Flux.then ⇢ com.openbrewery.beerbob.measurement.MeasurementFacade.save(MeasurementFacade.kt:21)
|_  Mono.doOnNext ⇢ com.openbrewery.beerbob.measurement.MeasurementFacade.save(MeasurementFacade.kt:22)
|_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ com.openbrewery.beerbob.measurement.MeasurementFacade.save(MeasurementFacade.kt:23)
```

Is there any way to read body once and re-use it in `measurementCollector` and `statusFacade` ?

Comment: does `statusFacade.save` accept MultiMeasurement? or only `Mono<MultiMeasurement>`?

Comment: Can do both since this is reactive mongo Repository

Comment: Did flatMap of `multiMeasurement` solve your issue?

Comment: I've added `cache()` on `multiMeasurement` before all operations

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `flatMap` the multiMeasurement mono, it will read the body once. Inside the flatMap rest of your code should be very similar. It should be something like this:

```
fun save(multiMeasurement: Mono<MultiMeasurement>) = multiMeasurement
    .flatMap { mm ->
        measurementCollector
            .save(mm.validate())
            .doOnNext { eventSender.sendEvent(it.toMeasurementItem()) }
            .then(statusFacade.save(mm))
            .doOnNext { eventSender.sendEvent(it.toStatusUpdateItem()) }
            .flatMap { toSettings(it.deviceId) }
    }
```

In your code, multiMeasurement mono is subscribed twice, that's the reason why you read the body twice. To avoid that, you need to flat the value from the mono once and then pass the actual value forward.